# How do I add to an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm doing the following but it doesn't work. it only has 1 item in the array no matter how many i add

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong

```
session_start();

$pid = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET["pid"]));
$price = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET["price"]));
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET["quantity"]));

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'] = $pid;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] = $quantity;

}else{
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'] = $pid;
    $_SESSION['total_price'] += $price;
    $_SESSION['total_items']  += $quantity;
}
```

Comment: Who gave the -1 without even bothering to leave a comment explaining the reason? The post follows all the rules in SO. Clear question, OP has made effort.... What else i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just resetting the values in the array. Every time you set $_SESSION['cart']['pid'] you are re-writing over the last value. However, your total_price and total_quantity are probably incrementing correctly right?

Use `$_SESSION['cart']['pid'][] = $pid;` instead. You need an array of 'pid' so that you can have multiple items. The [] operator tells php to treat the value as as array and push a new value onto the end of the array.

EDIT: Your initialization under the `if` should look like the following so that your ['pid'] is an array of pid's:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
$_SESSION['cart']['pid'] = array(); //this might be redundant...but I always initialize my variables
$_SESSION['cart']['pid'][] = $pid;
$_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] = $price;
$_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] = $quantity;
```

Under the `else` you would get:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['pid'][] = $pid;
$_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] += $price;
$_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] += $quantity;
```

Note: You forgot ['cart'] on the total_price and total_items under the `else` as was mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the ['cart'] to the bottom two $_SESSION setters:

```
$_SESSION['total_price'] += $price;
$_SESSION['total_items']  += $quantity;
```

change to

```
$_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] += $price;
$_SESSION['cart']['total_items']  += $quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['cart']['pid'] = $pid; 
$_SESSION['total_price'] += $price; 
$_SESSION['total_items']  += $quantity;
```

you forgot the ['cart'] in your else statemnt.. should be:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['pid'] = $pid; 
$_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] += $price; 
$_SESSION['cart']['total_items']  += $quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot ['cart'] in the last to session variables of the else statement.

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) for a list of array reference functions in php.